# MySQL: How to track a players total kills throughout his career

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure with 4 essential columns:

1. match_id
2. date
3. player_id
4. kills (of a player in the current game)

The table will have data for many different player_ids, and what I want to calculate is how many kills each player has generated in total (from all matches he has ever played at that given point in time) after each game ordered by date asc.

So for instance if he gets 20 kills in his first match, his career sum is 20. If he gets 15 kills in the next match his career kill is 35. I would like a query that shows each of these total career kills after each match.

Previously I solved this by looping through all the rows in python and keeping track of all the players kills, but I assume there is a much better way for this.

Comment: So how about a `GROUP BY player_id` while selecting `SUM(kills)` ?

Comment: with group by i calculate the players total kills throughout his entire career from now on until today (?) Whereas what I want is total career kills after each game. So for each game_id I want an updated "player total career kills"

Comment: And how do you differentiate between game instances? You should have some kind of encounter ID there.

Comment: game_id is unique for each game.

Comment: Game or game encounter? What do you mean by ‘game’. This description is really vague and generic. I mean I can play Quake3 three times a day, the game-id would stay the same but each match would have a unique match-id for every player I played with.

Comment: what you would call match_id is what I call  game_id here. Let me edit it to mach_id if that is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this kind of query can be easily achieved by [windows function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) which finally introduced in MySQL 8.0 :

```
select 
  player_id , 
  match_id , 
  date , 
  kills ,
  sum(kills) over (partition by player_id order by date asc , match_id asc) as career_kills
from `match`;
```

Here we rely on the default setting of window frame when `order by` is present in `over` , which is equivalent to `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cDRwe4azpkSc9MgmGc3qsC/1)

Comment: Thanks, but it returns the following error when I run it in DB fiddle (and in my own database)." Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match' at line 7"

Comment: `match` is MySQL reserved word.if you really want to use it as the table name ,enclose it with "`"